# Get current ISO datetime string using boost

Tags: date, datetime, boost, time, iso

Just trying to log timestamps to an output file like so:

```
//#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(now) << std::endl;

// ideally one line
std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(
            boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time()) << std::endl;
```

Getting errors in boost:

`boost::date_time::month_formatter<boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::date_time::iso_extended_format<char>, char>::format_month(boost::gregorian::greg_month const&, std::ostream&)':
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:44: undefined reference to`boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:49: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const'

I know this is probably a problem my end not boost but not sure how to debug, any ideas?

Comment: which version of boost do you use?

Answer (score 4):

You need to link the appropriate library.  Depending on your build system that might mean adding something like `-lboost_date_time` to your link or final build command.

Whenever you see "undefined reference" it means your code compiled just fine, but you have a library missing in your build.